# Zend Framework 2: Modify details of layout.pthml in controllers

Tags: model-view-controller, layout, zend-framework2

When I study skeleton application of `Zend Framework 2`, I want to add a label at upper-right of page to show the `UserName` who have logged in. But, I am confused at the code of the navigation bar that  was defined in `layout.pthml`,how can controller communicate with the `layout.phtml` to modify it?

Thanks in advance!

Furthermore, I want a login form upper-right of page when user not logged in using a helper.But i don't know how to add a form using helper,what should i do?

Comment: Why don't you go for session variable to save user name?

Comment: of course, push the user name into session in the controller, then use that value in the layout.

Answer (score 7):

From a controller you can use the controller plugin called “Layout” to set a variable:

```
$this->layout()->username = “some value”;
```

Then in layout.phtml you should be able to do:

```
<?php echo $this->username; ?>
```

If you take a look at `Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Layout` you will see that the `__invoke` method with no parameters will return an instance of `ViewModel`, hence why this works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define it module-wide, on your Module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
  ....
  $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('username', 'some_value');
}
```

and on your layout.phtml

```
echo $layout->username;
```

Answer (score 0):

In module.php u can do this

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
  ....
  $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('username', $username);
}
```

And in your layout u can do

```
echo $this->layout()->username;
```

Also check if u have used MvcEvent class.